# How do I get a batch file to autofill inputs prompted by a Java code

Tags: java, batch-file, automated-tests

I need to run a series of test cases for my java class through a batch file so that, when I run my batch file my java code runs 10 times auto filling the inputs that the java class prompts for.

There are three inputs that the class ask for and I don't know how to get my batch script to input variables into the running java code. This is what I've got so far:

```
set PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1\bin 
del *.class
echo compiling
javac *.java
java tempconvtr
pause
```

Comment: Hint: that is normally not how you test your java classes. There are frameworks like Junit that are explicitly meant for automation if java tests. So don't waste your time building your own test environment. Rather learn to apply the power of existing frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

In UNIX, to a java program you can auto feed input by piping.

Assuming your java program is expecting 3 input.
You can use following syntax inside your batch script where you are executing java program.

```
{ echo 'input1'; echo 'input2'; echo 'input3'; } | java -cp $CLASSPATH javaProgram
```

In UNIX the piping approach works:
For example following is the JAVA program which takes 3 input from user.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = null;
        try {
            // creating a Scanner object
            input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter an integer: ");

            // read an int value
            int data1 = input.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Using nextInt(): " + data1);

            // read an int value
            int data2 = input.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Using nextInt(): " + data2);

            // read an int value
            int data3 = input.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Using nextInt(): " + data3);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (input != null) {
                input.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If we normally execute it then:

```
jdk/bin/java -cp . Main
Enter an integer:
1
Using nextInt(): 1
2
Using nextInt(): 2
3
Using nextInt(): 3
```

Now I am piping in the inputs:

```
{ echo '1'; echo '2'; echo '3'; } |jdk/bin/java -cp . Main

Enter an integer:
Using nextInt(): 1
Using nextInt(): 2
Using nextInt(): 3
```

On Windows following is the equivalent way:

```
D:\workspace_europa\DatastructureAndAlgorithms\src>
(echo 1& echo 2& echo 3) | d:\InstalledProgramms\Java\jdk1.5.0_22\bin\java -cp . Main
    Enter an integer:
    Using nextInt(): 1
    Using nextInt(): 2
    Using nextInt(): 3
```

Comment: Can you explain the java -cp %CLASSPATH% portion. my batch file is in the same folder as the java class. Do I still need that portion? set PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1\bin
del *.class
echo compiling
javac *.java
{ echo 'K'; echo 'C'; echo '0'; } | java -cp tempconvtr 
echo All done
pause        This is what i tried but it is not working. I don't think the echos are being read since they are not color coded blue like the rest (i am using notepad++)

Comment: @KousikMandal, I've edited your Windows equivalent approach to use `&`, which separates individual commands, instead of `&&`, which runs a command only upon success of the previous one. In this case it will work with your `&&` implementation, because the `echo` commands have no reason to fail, but technically, it isn't correct. I also removed the trailing spaces, because `echo 1 & …` will include a trailing space, effectively sending two characters, not the intended single one.

Comment: @Compo, nice to see the changes you made. Yes I agree it's better to use single & over &&. In Unix we do it using semicolon(;) to mean OR . over AND.